# Are Teams Penalized for Lone Player Behaviour?

Tags: rules, football

If a player goes ballistic on the ref or other players, can this cause his team to be punished? I expect there have been several games where a team lost due to infractions from one of their players--but have teams ever been suspended or penalized beyond the match, due to the bad behaviour of one of their players? Presumably, this is more likely to be punished if they keep having bad players.

I was wondering about this primarily with Football, but am curious if this is the same across most sports.

Comment: I presume you are not including things like an incorrect eligibility under the scope of your question although an argument can be made that poor completion of administrative details is bad behaviour at a professional level. Please clarify.

Comment: @Nij Well, I was mostly thinking about bad behaviour on the field, rather than improper filling of forms or the like. Mostly fights that break out between players and sometimes with the referee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this happens in most team sports. In cricket, this is very prominent.

Usually if one player acts contrary to the "spirit of the game" they will be  warned, fined (depending on the level of cricket), and/or suspended - all increasingly harsh penalties. Often at higher levels, the captain is also fined/penalized for the poor behaviour of one of his teammates. If the situation really escalates, then the club is sanctioned, and I have seen an instance in schoolboy cricket where a team was disqualified from the grade due to obsessive and profuse bad language and abuse (this was however 2 players, not just a lone player).

Comment: Thank you for confirming this and giving some good examples, Avinash!